# IdentityServer3 Client to client authorization

Tags: identityserver3

I am in the process of implementing IdentityServer3 in our company but I have hit a blank around how to handle client to client authorization and would appreciate any pointer in the right direction.

This is a summary of our requirements:

- We have multiple web site clients that our users access. These are configured using the AuthorizationCode flow. Lets call these ***WebSiteClientA***, ***WebSiteClientB***.
- We have multiple WebAPI clients as back end services that could be accessed by either a client (***WebSiteClientA***, ***WebSiteClientB***) or a user (who has access to ***WebSiteClientA*** or ***WebSiteClientB***). Lets call this **WebAPIClientA**.

Note: Our company owns the users identity as well as all clients.

Initially I though we could configure ***WebAPIClientA*** using the ClientCredentials flow. Then ***WebSiteClientA*** \ ***WebSiteClientB*** would be configured with the client credentials for ***WebAPIClientA*** and could generate an access token when it required access to ***WebAPIClientA***, or alternatively generate an access token with limited scopes and hand this access token to the user so the user can access ***WebAPIClientA*** directly from the client side.

This would meet almost all our our requirements except 1 big one, we also want to be able to manage what scopes a client has access to for another client and with the approach of using the ClientCredentials flow anyone with the client credentials would be able to generate access tokens for all scopes under that client. ie ***WebSiteClientA*** should be able to generate an access token for ***WebAPIClientA*** with read & write scopes but ***WebSiteClientB*** should only be able to generate an access token for ***WebAPIClientA*** with the read scope.

In my mind the client\identity server conversation would be:
***WebSiteClientA*** makes a request to the identity server for an access token to ***WebAPIClientA*** for scope X and provides the client secret for ***WebSiteClientA***. The identity server then says yes, you are ***WebSiteClientA*** and we can see from our records you have access to ***WebAPIClientA*** with scope X, here is an access token.

Is this possible or am I looking at this in the completely wrong way and there is maybe a better approach to meeting the requirements?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're talking about two things.

The first is that in the APIs you need the user's id. To obtain the user id you have a decision if you want to build a trusted subsystem, or if you don't want a trusted subsystem (in the sense that your APIs trust or don't trust the MVC client to pass along the user's identifier). If you do a trusted subsystem, then the client credentials flow from the MVC client to the API is fine. If you don't want a trusted subsystem, then you need the MVC client to obtain an access token for the user (via implicit or hybrid flow).

The second issue you're asking about is if you can control the scopes each client is allowed to request, and you can via the `AllowedScopes` configuration property (or whatever it's called) on the client configuration. This setting is orthogonal to the first issue mentioned above.